# Is it possible to use Qt Creator 2.7 with visual studio 2012 compiler and have all its features?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

Not long time ago I started to *have some fun* with c++ and Qt seemed the right place for a noob to begin. 
I installed Qt 5.0.0 with Qt Creator 2.5 and Visual Studio 2010 Express for the compiler and everything was ok, I was able to write a simple application and run it.

From what i've seen Visual Studio 2012 offers almost all features of c++11 and my question is: If i install the new Qt 5.0.2 + Qt Creator 2.7 and visual studio 2012 will i be able to use it as a compiler and use all the features presented [here](http://cpprocks.com/a-comparison-of-c11-language-support-in-vs2012-g-4-7-and-clang-3-1/) (lambdas, smart pointers, move semantics,etc) ?

PS: I use Windows 7 64 bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Creator supports the MSVC2012 compiler and the features depend on the compiler, not Creator. This is how I've been using Qt for a while.

Note that the IDE itself might not have support for some new C++11 features when it comes to checking your code, but even if you get errors or warnings, as long as your code is valid, it will compile.

Comment: I see, I have Visual Studio 2012 already installed so i will install Qt 5.0.2 and Qt Creator 2.7 then. Thank you.